# Java Script, How to Start? Linking Files to Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sublimetext3

I wish to run these code on sublime but i don't know how to link the appropriate Javasript/JQuery.

Any help would be very much appreciated. (This is my first question on this) :)

Taken from http://jqueryui.com/toggle/.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Effects - Toggle Demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  .toggler {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
  }
  #button {
    padding: .5em 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  #effect {
    position: relative;
    width: 240px;
    height: 135px;
    padding: 0.4em;
  }
  #effect h3 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.4em;
    text-align: center;
  }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    // run the currently selected effect
    function runEffect() {
      // get effect type from
      var selectedEffect = $( "#effectTypes" ).val();

      // most effect types need no options passed by default
      var options = {};
      // some effects have required parameters
      if ( selectedEffect === "scale" ) {
        options = { percent: 0 };
      } else if ( selectedEffect === "size" ) {
        options = { to: { width: 200, height: 60 } };
      }

      // run the effect
      $( "#effect" ).toggle( selectedEffect, options, 500 );
    };

    // set effect from select menu value
    $( "#button" ).click(function() {
      runEffect();
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="toggler">
  <div id="effect" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">Toggle</h3>
    <p>
      Etiam libero neque, luctus a, eleifend nec, semper at, lorem. Sed pede. Nulla lorem metus, adipiscing ut, luctus sed, hendrerit vitae, mi.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<select name="effects" id="effectTypes">
  <option value="blind">Blind</option>
  <option value="bounce">Bounce</option>
  <option value="clip">Clip</option>
  <option value="drop">Drop</option>
  <option value="explode">Explode</option>
  <option value="fold">Fold</option>
  <option value="highlight">Highlight</option>
  <option value="puff">Puff</option>
  <option value="pulsate">Pulsate</option>
  <option value="scale">Scale</option>
  <option value="shake">Shake</option>
  <option value="size">Size</option>
  <option value="slide">Slide</option>
</select>

<button id="button" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">Run Effect</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the jQuery, you can use the hosted version as follows:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

For the jQuery UI,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

I don't think you need any extra file for Javascript, as it's included in your code within `<script></script>` tags

Comment: Worked perfect :) It's for a project and you're a life saver! :)

Answer (score 1):

Everything is fine. While importing the external files, change `//` to `http://` as in:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Also, you may like to remove or fix this line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
```

as it represents a relative path and you ought to have a file 'style.css' in the location specified.

Comment: Having only `//` is fine! it picks up the protocol of the current page, whether http or https. I _encourage_ my team to use just `//`.

Comment: But I wonder why didn't it work for me and then worked with the fix I mentioned.